# Bokeh 'single-value' widget

Tags: python, bokeh

Is it possible to create something like below in Bokeh, or will this require customJS? Seems like a fairly simple request (at least in terms of what other similar libraries offer) but can't find anything in the documentation.

[image: Widget]

Comment: Yes you could create this using a bokeh server. Essentially this is a div element that is formatted and styled using css. All of that is possible with bokeh, see https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#div. Does this need to be updated? if so theres no way around that - either you need to use python based callbacks, or customJS.

Comment: Yep - it would need to be updated. I should be able to do this with Python and then I assume the CSS will be a template where the numbers could be updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core Bokeh component to use is the Div object.

```
template=("""
      <div class='content'>
       <div class='name'> {stock_name} </div>
        <span class='number'>{price}<small>{price_unit}</small> </span>
        <span class='percentage' style='color: {colour};'> {percentage}<small>%</small> </span>
      </div>
      """)
# initial text
text = template.format(stock_name = stock_name,
                   price=price,
                   price_unit='k',
                   percentage=percentage,
                   colour='#97D389')
div = Div(text=text, height=300)
```

That can then be added to the document, and displayed to the user.

As a complete example, I have created an example gist, which has the numbers periodically updating -
 see https://gist.github.com/anthonydouc/c8571f0a2f9aa8415bd566e1ac2ba237. There are instructions in a comment at the bottom of the gist for how to structure the application - make a folder called "stocktext" and construct the subfolders as indicated, then run `'bokeh serve -- show stocktext'`

Example output:
[image: Screenshot from application]

Largely used the streaming example (https://demo.bokeh.org/surface3d), to have the numbers automatically updates.

The entire content is just contained within a simple html div element, the usage with Bokeh is explained here:

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#div

Lastly, to enable python based callbacks you need to run a bokeh server - see https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html for more info.

Comment: Thanks a lot for doing this - it was very kind of you to invest that much time. I'll let you know how I get on!

Comment: not a problem, if it all works out, would be great to accept the answer if it has addressed your question